# Incorrect PNG Colouring (Swapped channels?)

Tags: image, png, image-manipulation

Please can someone take a look at the following image:
http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/6885/colouring.png

I need to make the bottom image the same as the first. It appears the colour channels are wrong, but I'm not sure and can't correct it.

Please can someone tell me how to go from the bottom image to the top image?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Thank you, swapping the red and blue channels fixed it!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the two source files as separate links?

Comment: URL is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've swapped red and blue. Perhaps a byte ordering problem?